# how can you tell if phishing email link was clicked by using logs

Tags: phishing

100 employees of a company received an email with a phishing link, How can I tell who clicked on the email phishing link and how many got infected with malware? 3 logs were given, email log, web server log and I believe firewall log (but not sure).

This was a question on the CompTIA CySA+ exam

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are these employees? random people on the Internet? Do you have an email server? etc. etc. This is like asking "how do you drive?" except you haven't told us whether you want to drive a car, motorcycle, truck, ship, or space shuttle.

Comment: If you're the attacker, you presumably left tracking bits in the payload links, therefore you have it all in your web server logs. If you're a network admin, you might have the monitoring in place to see what your users connect to, in which case you can track it that way. If you're very well set up, you can also find the email campaign in your mail server logs, identify which of your users received the attack, and then narrow your search to their computers' connections.

Comment: So, the question is, what log would have the best data? And what do you think?